# Server 2012 R2 Properties Dropdown and Ribbon

Tags: properties, ribbon, windows-server-2012-r2

These two screenshots are from two different Windows Server 2012 R2 machines. They were both deployed from ISO and patched to current.

Why does right-clicking on "This PC" result in a dropdown menu on one machine, but a ribbon on the other? The former also has a more convenient power/restart button. Is this a simple setting issue?

Winver shows the OS to be the same on both machines.

[image: Dropdown]

[image: Ribbon]

[image: Winver]

Answer (score 1):

Simple. The server in the first screenshot has the `Windows 8.1/Server 2012 R2 Update 1` installed, whilst the server in the second screenshot does not, resulting in the changes in UI.

The way to identify the update is the power options located next to the profile picture.